# Firebase Phone Auth OTP to whatsapp

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, whatsapp

I have created an app that uses Firebase phone auth but there are a lot of problems with the OTP sending process sometimes it takes too much time, and sometimes it does not even send the OTP (may be due to the daily limit that they have),

So I want to send the OTP to the user's WhatsApp as well to ensure that the user receives OTP instantly.
How can I achieve this so that the OTP sent on the user's WhatsApp is the same as the OTP generated by Firebase, if it cannot be the same and I have to generate it myself then how can I still sign in the user, and create a user in firebase authentication with the phone number entered?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Sending the exact same OTP generated by Firebase to WhatsApp can be challenging due to several factors, including security considerations and the lack of a direct API for WhatsApp message sending. However, you can achieve a similar user experience by generating your own OTP for WhatsApp delivery while maintaining Firebase's OTP for authentication purposes.

Comment: @k0uva Yes I can deliver a random OTP using the WhatsApp API but the problem is that I cannot authenticate the user on firebase without the correct OTP. if there is a way to create a user on Firebase authentication without having to use the correct OTP, please tell me about it. I have to create a user in Firebase authentication to read data from the Firebase database. Thank You